# Heading element doesn't always change when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html

Sometimes, when I refresh the page `<h1>` element doesn't change and stays as "Refresh Me!".
I wonder what is the reason of that problem..

```js
var randomNumberOne = Math.floor((Math.random())*6) + 1;
var diceImageOne = "dice" + randomNumberOne + ".png";
document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src",diceImageOne);

var randomNumberTwo = Math.floor((Math.random())*6) + 1;
var diceImageTwo = "dice" + randomNumberTwo + ".png";
document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src",diceImageTwo);


if(randomNumberOne > randomNumberTwo ){
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = " Play 1 Wins!";
}
else if (randomNumberTwo > randomNumberOne ){
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHtml = "Player 2 Wins! ";
}
else{
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Draw!";
}
```

```html
      <div class="containerr">
        <h1>Refresh Me!</h1>
        <div class="dice">
            <p>Player 1</p>
            <img src="dice6.png" class="img1" alt="img1">
        </div>
        <div class="dice">
            <p>Player 2</p>
            <img src="dice6.png"  class="img2" alt="img2">
        </div>
      </div>  
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: In the `else if` you're setting `innerHtml`, the code fails every time player 2 wins.

Comment: I got it, but How can ı solve this?

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no DOM attribute such as `innerHtml`. Changing it to `innerHTML` solves the issue.

```js
var randomNumberOne = Math.floor((Math.random())*6) + 1;
var diceImageOne = "dice" + randomNumberOne + ".png";
document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src",diceImageOne);

var randomNumberTwo = Math.floor((Math.random())*6) + 1;
var diceImageTwo = "dice" + randomNumberTwo + ".png";
document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src",diceImageTwo);


if(randomNumberOne > randomNumberTwo ){
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = " Play 1 Wins!";
}
else if (randomNumberTwo > randomNumberOne ){
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins! ";
}
else{
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Draw!";
}
```

```html
      <div class="containerr">
        <h1>Refresh Me!</h1>
        <div class="dice">
            <p>Player 1</p>
            <img src="dice6.png" class="img1" alt="img1">
        </div>
        <div class="dice">
            <p>Player 2</p>
            <img src="dice6.png"  class="img2" alt="img2">
        </div>
      </div>  
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: oo My god! I must be blind thanks both of you :)